# MySQL use of REGEXP or LIKE to select table name with database alias

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table as follows:

```
id    |                query                 -
------------------------------------------------
1     | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`user`;
2     |  INSERT INTO `test`.`user` (id,name,email)
         VALUES      ('4','Don','don@quikr.com');
3     | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`data`;
```

I want to get rows with "`test`.`user`" patterns in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE LOWER(query) LIKE '%`test`.`user`%'
```

This assumes you don't have any spaces around the `.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `query` LIKE '%test%user%'
```

The % is the wildcard. You can put it at the front, back, or in the middle, and it can be used multiple times. The query above will find anything that has "test" and "user" in that order, with any characters in between, before or after.

Comment: Check the use case where it fails:
SELECT main.id, usr.name
FROM `test`.`main` main 
INNER JOIN `db`.`user` usr;

Answer (score 0):

You can get more control over pattern matches in your queries if you use `REGEXP`, e.g.

```
select `query` from test WHERE `query` REGEXP '.*test.*user.*';
```

Gives a basic structure for a query using `REGEXP`, this works for the question you have asked, but can be modified according to your needs.

As shown in this [demo sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0479d5/3)

For a list of available meta character that work with `REGEXP` see - http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

Comment: The above query fails if we have a table name such as "user_duplicate" or "usersomething".